# When is it a security risk to publish the database structure?

Tags: database, security, web

I'm planning a site which needs the users' trust. To help trust building, I was thinking to publish the source code, the database schema and even allow users to download raw data (so they can run their own queries on the data to verify that the site gives the correct answers).

Under which circumstances is that a security risk? My thinking is that most of the data can be grazed off the site with a web spider anyway.

For sensitive information like IP addresses and passwords, I plan to store that hashed (with a salt). Age information is not relevant, maybe I'll just store "adult yes/no". Anything that I'm missing?

Comment: What about emails? I guess you shouldn't allow just anyone to download bunch of them, and keeping them hashed wouldn't do you much good if you need to contact someone.

Comment: It would make searching for an SQL injection opportunity or other vulnerability a lot easier. In the long run your program would be even safer, but it could be a long road.

Comment: @Henk: That's the idea. There will be only very few places where I need to build queries manually and most of them will use parameters, so I'm not worried too much about SQLI. But there might be other vulnerabilities.

Comment: @rebus: excellent point. But I could hash them and keep the real ones in a second, private database.

Comment: If you keep them in a second database, you don't need them in the first, do you?
OTOH you could always remove the password/age information from the database dumps before publishing.

Comment: I'd rather remove private data completely from the public dumps. It's easy to make mistakes when trying to anonymize such data.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: I agree. Since I need a second, private database for the emails anyway, that's a much more simple and secure solution. It even allows me to use the built-in back/restore to dump the data. Users will see it's schema in the source, so they will know what I store there and why, so no trust issue here as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Injection is not an issue if you do your data access properly. You are not worried about keeping your model proprietary so no issue there. You have the green light to expose the model.

Privacy is not an issue if you inform user's the data is public. People expose private info and photos on Facebook so why not your system? Green light.

Hashed data with a random salt in theory is safe to download. SHA512 with a random hash will probably never be broken. But who knows? At one time MD5 was the "right way" to hash, and now you find a collision in under 1 hour.

The only issue is private data that needs to be encrypted, not hashed. You can't hash an IP because you will want to use the actual IP at some point in the future. You can't hash credit card numbers because you will need the real credit card number at some point. You will be forced to utilize a private key and deal with the weakness of keeping it private. By exposing data you totally remove a layer of physical security. Encryption + physical is better than encryption alone.

Comment: In my case, I need the information about distinct IP addresses to fight vote fraud but I don't need the actual IP address.

Comment: If you publish the salt an attacker can trivially reverse the hash of an IPv4.